# How autorun OpenSocial gadget in IBM Rational DOORs Next Generation

Tags: javascript, opensocial, ibm-doors

I'm developing an IBM Rational DOORs Next Generation (RDNG) extension which is really a Javascript code realized in accordance to rules of OpenSocial API, and placed into Minidashboard panel. The problem is that I would like to start this code automatically. But I found that it can not be started until I open Minidashboard panel at least once after coming to RDNG from outside. But this is not good if I want to automate the users' activities because some users can forget to show Minidashboard, and so on.
The question is, may be somebody knows a way how to start such a hidden code, or may be automatically open Minidashboard panel. Could somebody help me in this way?
Code which is called with OpenSocial gadget:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!--
 Licensed Materials - Property of Softacus
 main_DoorsIDScript.xml
© Copyright Softacus 2017

-->
<Module specificationVersion="2.0">
<ModulePrefs title="DOORs_ID" height="300" scrolling="true">
    <Optional feature="com.ibm.rdm.rm.api"/>
</ModulePrefs>
<Content type="html">
    <![CDATA[
        <html>
            <head>
                <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
                <script src="js/common.js"></script>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/common.css">
            </head>
            <body>
                <h3>RDNG ID Auto</h3>
                <p id="messages" class="info"></p>
                <p id="errors" class="warning"></p>
            </body>
        </html>
    ]]>
</Content>
</Module>
```

The default function in the "common.js" file:

```
$(function() {
    if (window.location.href.search("/rm/") < 0) {
        $("#messages")
                .append("The script works in DOORs Next Generation only!");
    } else {
        RM.Event.subscribe(RM.Event.ARTIFACT_SAVED, function(saved) {
            // console.log("Caught next number of saved artifacts: " +
            // saved.length);
...
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Please share some code whatever you have tried

Comment: I have added some code into the question, but I'm not sure that this has a sense. The matter is that the gadget's content (I mean the Javascript code, any JS code) doesn't take place in a debugger even until the Minidashboard panel is open at least once.